# Router interferes with mouse and keyboard

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, logitech-mouse, interference, logitech-keyboard

I have a DD-WRT router running in client bridge mode and it interferes with my mouse intermittently. unplugging the router fixes it, but is not an option.
my mouse and keyboard are a logitech k270 and the dd-wrt is a dir-615 e4 running a 2010 build of dd-wrt.

Comment: Do your WiFi devices support 5 GHz? Use that.

Comment: Try Bluetooth co-existance mode if it's in the advanced wireless settings. (It depends on the wireless radio). It seemed to help with my old router/keyboard and mouse that did this. The problem was none existant when I went to 802.11ac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use the same frequency range, so interference is not that surprising. Try moving the router and all antennas around a bit, often a few centimeters can change the situation, because of the interference pattern. Another option is to switch channels on the router (and set it to a fixed channel). A third option is to use metal/aluminium foil in suitable places to shield the devices from each other (but that can be difficult, because of reflections).